# Should I ever store the result of set/map find() as reference?

Tags: c++

Please consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <set>

int main ()
{
  std::set<int> s;

  const auto it = s.find(1);
  const auto& it2 = s.find(1);

  return 0;
}
```

One could assume that `it2` would be cheaper, but if I understand the [generated assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/x3eYcMeca) correctly, it actually uses two more instructions:

```
        //const auto it = s.find(1);
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-32], 1
        lea     rdx, [rbp-32]
        lea     rax, [rbp-80]
        mov     rsi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::find(int const&)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-88], rax

        // const auto& it2 = s.find(1);
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], 1
        lea     rdx, [rbp-28]
        lea     rax, [rbp-80]
        mov     rsi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::find(int const&)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-96], rax
        lea     rax, [rbp-96]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rax
```

I tried the code with various compilers (clang, gcc) and containers (map, unordered_map, unordered_set) and the result seems to be consistent.

Is my understanding of the assembly code correct (using a reference is more costly)?

Is there any use case where `it2` (reference to iterator) would be preferred over `it` (iterator) as result of calling `find()` on `map`/`set`?

Comment: `std::set::find()` returns an iterator.  Iterators are cheap to copy around.  It is rare that you ever need a reference to an iterator. In most cases, you should treat them as simple value types.

Comment: You are compiling without optimizations turned on.

Comment: What is it a reference to? Find returns the iterator by value, so the extra cost is probably for making a temporary so that you have something to reference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Yes, I turned off optimizations as otherwise the compiler would just skip most of the code in the example.

Comment: Hmm, if it's a temporary, fun stuff will happen if you try to return that reference out of the current function.

Comment: @MartinBG Then in a bigger program where the code is not "skipped", you don't know what the compiler will do when optimizations are turned on.  Maybe the compiler will do an optimization trick that the toy example cannot show you.  Give an example where the code *won't* be skipped **and** you have optimizations turned on.

Comment: @dratenik Yes, it seems that returned iterator is stored "somewhere" and the address to that location is retrieved (asm `lea`) and assigned to `it2` (asm `mov`).

Comment: More specifically it is stored on the stack in the current stack frame and will silently go out of scope on return. (see fun stuff above)

Comment: @mch except when the temporary is assigned to a `const` reference, then the temporary's lifetime is extended to match the lifetime of the reference

Comment: @mch If I understand you correctly one should never use the `it2` from the example as it is not guaranteed to have the correct data?

Comment: @MartinBG no, I forgot about the `const` as Remy Lebeau wrote. Sorry.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Here is an example with enabled compiler optimizations, but the assembly code is too cryptic to me: https://godbolt.org/z/ejGd4z1of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set::find() doesn't return a reference:

```
const_iterator find (const value_type& val) const;
iterator       find (const value_type& val);
```

I'm surprised the compiler let you assign the value to a reference. As some of the commenters have suggested, it creates a temporary for your reference to point to.

C++ is really quite efficient if you do this:

```
auto ptr = set.find(...)
```

When a method doesn't return a reference, you probably don't want to assign it to a reference.

Comment: `const auto& iter = ` will hust extend the lifetmie of a temporary object. So "when a method doesn't return a reference" it is perfectly fine to assign it to a reference

Comment: >The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference (since C++11), see reference initialization for details.   (cppreference)

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik whether the code works or not, it still seems like something odd to do.

Comment: yet it is perfectly fine. Moreover, with template code writing `const auto& v = ...` or `auto&& v =...` is a way to go, since otherwise you might *force* the compiler to construct an object.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik If you know the method doesn't return a reference, then it's less efficient, whether it works or not. But we can agree to disagree.